# convert MST timezone (data saved in mysql )datetime to IST and display in angularjs page

Tags: angularjs

Mysql is saving date time in MST but I want it in IST. checked with godaddy support but got to know that it cannot be changed. Now my task is to change it in angularjs.

Tried this javascript :

```
<script>
var msec = Date.parse("{{history.created_datetime}}");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =new Date(msec);;
</script>
<td id="demo"></td>
```

Comment: if you add a minimal example which replicates the issues you're having... the sO community could help

Comment: @SSD pls add a snippet or code with replicated issue!

Comment: What is the value of `history.created_datetime`

Comment: In database  it is saved like this: 2018-12-11 05:09:02. Which is wrong. According to IST it should be 2018-12-12 . MST is 12:30 mints behind .